# Python selenium - presence_of_all_elements_located not working

Tags: python, selenium

I just wrote this simple test in which it submits the form and tried to find values in the todo app. But it not working. I'm using `WebDriverWait` to wait until the page loads after form submission. But it is not waiting for the page to load and I don't know why.

Please help me out, what is wrong with this code?

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class NewUserTest(TestCase):
    """
    Test for a new user actions 
    """

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(10)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def check_row_in_table(self, rowItem):
        rows = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#todo-items-table tr')
            )
        )

        self.assertIn(
            rowItem,
            [row.text for row in rows]
        )

    def test_starting_a_new_todo_list(self):
        """
        Test for when a user creates a new todo list
        """

        # Check title
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        self.assertIn('To-Do', self.browser.title)

        # check header text - h1
        header = self.browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h1')
        self.assertEqual(header.text, 'To-Do List')

        # check inputbox for new to-do
        inputbox = self.browser.find_element(By.ID, 'todo-item')
        self.assertEqual(inputbox.get_attribute(
            'placeholder'), 'Enter a to-do item')

        # add 2 new item to to-do list
        inputbox.send_keys("Go to gym")
        inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        self.check_row_in_table('1. Go to gym')

        # inputbox = self.browser.find_element(By.ID, 'todo-item')
        # inputbox.send_keys("Prepare breakfast")
        # inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        # self.check_row_in_table('1. Go to gym')
        # self.check_row_in_table('2. Prepare breakfast')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It shows me the following error.

```
➜ python functional_test.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_starting_a_new_todo_list (__main__.NewUserTest)
Test for when a user creates a new todo list
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_test.py", line 53, in test_starting_a_new_todo_list
    self.check_row_in_table('1. Go to gym')
  File "functional_test.py", line 28, in check_row_in_table
    [row.text for row in rows]
  File "functional_test.py", line 28, in <listcomp>
    [row.text for row in rows]
  File "/home/pkkulhari/.virtualenvs/todo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 76, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "/home/pkkulhari/.virtualenvs/todo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 693, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/pkkulhari/.virtualenvs/todo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pkkulhari/.virtualenvs/todo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <tr> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:181:5
StaleElementReferenceError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:442:5
element.resolveElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:686:11
evaluate.fromJSON@chrome://remote/content/marionette/evaluate.js:253:26
evaluate.fromJSON@chrome://remote/content/marionette/evaluate.js:261:29
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.jsm:79:29
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a stale element reference exception, what it means is that you may have redirected to a new page after having interaction with the first element, and while coming back to the original page the elements are stale. A simple solution is to redefine the list of web elements again.

**Code :**

```
def check_row_in_table(self, rowItem):
    WebDriverWait(self.browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#todo-items-table tr')))
    total_number_of_row = len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#todo-items-table tr"))
    j = 0
    for i in range(total_number_of_row):
        elems = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#todo-items-table tr")
        self.assertIn(rowItem, elems[j].text)
        j = j + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the function check_row_in_table() function according to @cruisepandey's answer, and now It is working fine.

**Code:**

```js
def check_row_in_table(self, rowItem):
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 5).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#todo-items-table tr')))

        rows = self.browser.find_elements(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#todo-items-table tr')

        self.assertIn(
            rowItem,
            [row.text for row in rows]
        )
```